# Delphi XE - Installation problem on W7/64 virtual machine

Tags: delphi, windows-7, installation, 64-bit, delphi-xe

We bought Delphi XE to slowly upgrade from Delphi 6.
Delphi 6 is well working in Win7/X64.

I installed two virtual machines to test it (I planned three of them, but Virtual PC is not supports X64 guest OS).

1.) Sun VirtualBox 4.x
2.) VMWARE player latest

The guest OS is Win7/X64. Latest SP's, packs are installed.

I set local "area" settings to "english-usa".
I started the installer as admin.

The phenomenon is:
The InstallAware is starting, the progress bar is access the 100%.
After this a new InstallAware Window is starting, but later it disappeared.
Then nothing happens. Sometimes the Windows say (dialog) that setup is not working, will I reinstall it?

The event log is not containing information about the problem.

I tried to starting "setup.exe" directly with "as admin", but the result is same.
I tried to find the real setup files in "Local Settings/Temp", and starting it directly as admin, but I got same result.

So I'm very disappointment, and puzzled... We bought something that is not installable.
May I can install the XE into VPC/XP Mode; but I'm sure the somebody CAN install this software in Win7/X64... :-(

Can anybody help me, how to continue the installation?
How to "debug"?

Thanks for your help:
   dd

Comment: It works perfectly well on my Win7 x64 machines and on so many similar machines of Stack Overflow users. I'd point the finger at your VMs. Why are you installing an IDE into a VM? I wouldn't touch XP with a barge pole. Have you contacted Embarcadero support?

Comment: Do you use the ISO image to install or the downloaded setup? Do you have internet access inside the VM?

Comment: Support is free for installation issues from Embarcadero directly. You should file a support case with them. SO is not for providing support for software installation problems; vendors have tech support for that themselves.

Comment: I'd say Win7 x64 is a pretty popular platform amongst programmers those days: It's Win7, and that's good (and almost required), and it allows for more then 3Gb of RAM, that's very good. I bet lots of developers at Embarcadero use this exact sweet combination for Delphi's development. And if it matters, I'm running Delphi 2010 in a VmWare virtual machine running... Win7 x64, so I can give my VM 8Gb of ram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was if I copy the zip file directly into VM (not download it), and I must **set ALL AREA FLAGS** to USA.
The language, the area, the format settings - all things!

Then the installer simply working...

Thank you for your help!

Regards:
    dd

Answer (score 1):

It might be a problem with your virtual machine, i have myself issues with VirtualBox.

You also should double check if you dont have a corrupted Iso. Try to download it again to see it works.

I work in a software house that have at least 30 people working with Delphi XE on their Windows 7 machines. None of them ever reported a installation crash.

Another good question: are you executing the setup.exe as administrator?

Comment: +1. You can't execute "setup.exe" as anything but Administrator on Win7. Rename Notepad.exe to Setup.exe and it will require elevation!